# How to configure multiple spring cloud config servers in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring boot 2.4 and application related properties are stored in spring cloud config server. It works fine and I am able to read all properties in the application. Below properties have been configured in application.properties for this purpose.

```
spring.application.name=app-prop-config
spring.cloud.config.label=61465
spring.cloud.config.enable=true
spring.config.import=configserver:https://vmcloud-configsvc.farm-dev.ab.com
```

The above properties translates to:  **https://vmcloud-configsvc.farm-dev.ab.com/61465/app-prop-config-dev.properties**

Per my requirement, I need to read few more properties as well and these properties are already available in another spring cloud config server which can be accessed using:

```
spring.application.name=common-prop-config
spring.cloud.config.label=61468
spring.cloud.config.enable=true
spring.config.import=configserver:https://vmcloud-common-configsvc.farm.ab.com
```

The above properties translates to:  **https://vmcloud-common-configsvc.farm.ab.com/61468/common-prop-config-dev.properties**

The above config server(https://vmcloud-common-configsvc.farm.ab.com) properties have been used by multiple applications and duplicating properties into my config server(https://vmcloud-configsvc.farm-dev.ab.com) would cause maintenance issue in future as any change in properties have to get updated in 2 servers.

***Is it possible to use above 2 spring cloud config servers in spring boot app so that I don't have to copy required properties into my existing config server?***

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's working for me when i use bootstrap first config. You can put multiple config name that you want to load. For example if you want to retreive user-service.properties et data-rest.properties in the same app your bootstrap.properties should be like:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri= http://config-server-host
spring.cloud.config.name= user-service, data-rest
```